# Inspect a component's children recursively in render method

Tags: reactjs

I created a component called `labeledElement` which basically simply generates

```
<label {...props}>
    <span class="label">{props.label}</span>
    {props.children}
</label>
```

However, this is a problem if children contains multiple inputs or buttons since labels propagate clicks and focuses to children. In this scenario I would like to use a `div` rather than a label.

Is it possible in my `render` method to analyze children, see if there are more than one child matches `'button input textarea select'`, and depending on this output a label or a div?

I have some thoughts on how to hack it together, but all of these require wiring up to `componentDidMount`, inspecting the DOM and adjusting state which seems like definitely the *wrong* way of doing things.

Comment: Can you pass in an extra prop from the `labeledElement`'s parent instead?

Comment: @rossta yeah, that's what I'm doing now, but Reactjs should have all the information already that this decision has to be based on

Comment: How about mapping over the `ReactElement` collection returned by `{this.props.children}` and inspecting object properties? You may be able to get what you want from the types and props of the children.

Comment: @rossta that was my first thought as well but that seems to only show me one-level deep. But then again, there might be some way to go down further, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recursively iterate over children like this:

```
function visitReactElements(element, callback, depth=0) => {
  if (!element || !element.props) return;

  callback(element, depth);

  React.Children.forEach(element.props.children, (element) => {
    visitReactElements(element, callback, depth + 1);
  });
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fexalafaca/1/edit?js,console)

You're going down a path that takes simple react and twists it into a complicated magical beast. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but I think what you are looking for is this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-if

you can than simple count/inspect you children props and render properly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please clarify in the comments what's unclear? I expressed the issue and gave a specific example - I don't really know how to ask it more to the point. The problem is not that I don't know how to do an `if` (I don't use jsx anyways so its very easy) but that I don't know **how to recursively inspect all children**. This is all information that react should have at the time the `render` method is called, but how do I extract it?

Comment: well I don't know how the data structure in your props.children is and cannot help you with how to inspect it, so I assumed that you asked how to render it accordingly.

Comment: when I call `myComponent({}, label({}, "hi", input() ) )` the results of the `label()` call are passed *into* `myComponent`. The results of `label` are a ReactElement that's a descriptor of what's going on with that component. This includes all children. So all that data **must** be available for the `render` method. I simply don't know how to get at it.

Comment: Have you gotten the `react-tools` chrome extension? It let's you click on any dom elements and see their react props/state.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small library to deal with the React.Children structure and you can execute a deep find to see if there are one or more tags that match.

Here is the library:
https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities

You can use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Children from 'react-children-utilities';

function labeledElement(props) {

    const hasTags = !!Children.deepFind(props.children, child => ['button', 'input', 'textarea', 'select'].includes(child.type));
    const Element = hasTags ? 'div' : 'label';

    return (
        <Element {...props}>
            <span class="label">{props.label}</span>
            {props.children}
        </Element>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight twist on the accepted answer:

```js
function visitReactElements(children, callback, depth = 0) {
  if (!children) return;

  callback(children, depth);

  React.Children.forEach(children, (el) => {
    visitReactElements(el.children, callback, depth + 1);
  });
}

const WrapperComponent = ({ children }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    visitReactElements(children, console.log);
  }, [children]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, upvoted. This question was created before hooks so this feels like it might be useful to other people